# Periodic feature layer for Lotka-Volterra approximation

Tags: neural-networks, models, function-approximation, feature-selection

I am working with DeepXDE, a SciML library that can be used to solve differential equations. I came across [this demo page for solving a Lotka-Volterra system](https://deepxde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos/pinn_forward/lotka.volterra.html). Since the solutions are known to be cyclic, they define an `input_transform` that with several `sin(kt)` functions that "[force] the prediction to be periodic".

While this intuitively makes sense, I don't understand mathematically why this should work. In particular, how do the choices of the different `k` affect the output, and why also have a non-periodic term? In general, I would also appreciate seeing examples of other neural networks designed in this kind of way, taking into account domain knowledge to design certain feature layers.

Comment: You are correct, that the solution becomes periodic does not imply that the period is automatically $2\pi$. There should be at least a base frequency that is a adaptable parameter, and the trigonometric basis should be complete, that is, contain the corresponding cosines.